# How to remap the "Send tweet" hotkey?

Tags: macos, sharing, twitter, notifications

In Mountain Lion there is a "tweet sheet" when sharing from either notification center or an app. The default hotkey for "send tweet" is <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. I'd like to use something like <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>. Is there a way to remap this?

Answer (score 1):

[You can use Spark to set custom keybindings for nearly anything in OS X](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php). You can set up a shortcut to execute an AppleScript and use the following script:

```
display dialog "Tweet?" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
set mytweet to text returned of result

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Notification Center"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        click button 1 of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window "window"
        keystroke mytweet
        keystroke "D" using {command down, shift down}
        keystroke space
    end tell
end tell
```

Source: [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/08/21/send-a-tweet-via-notification-center-using-this-handy-applescrip/)